# brew (cask) update doesn't work

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

Could somebody help me here. I try to update flux (from 36.5 to 36.6).

```
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.

$ brew cask list
....
flux
...

$ brew cask info flux
flux: 36-6
f.lux
https://justgetflux.com/
Not installed
https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/flux.rb
==> Contents
  Flux.app (app)

$ brew cask update flux
Updated 1 tap (caskroom/cask).
No changes to formulae.
```

I got the same behavior with other packages. What's wrong? I also run brew doctor and brew cleanup.

Thanks
Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Homebrew, Homebrew Cask can’t upgrade packages. `brew cask update` is just an alias for `brew update` which updates Homebrew (Cask) itself.

The only way to “upgrade” an Homebrew cask is either to use its built-in update mecanism (see e.g. Chrome) or to remove it and install it again.